# Codeigniter - How to do work on server, after view file is shown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

### What is the best way of spitting out the view file in codeigniter and still doing some work on the server? The situation basically is:

1. I have a payPal checkout where user goes to paypal and clicks Pay Now! A set_express_checkout() is called to start things off.
2. The user is returned to the Thank You page.
3. I have to call a Get_express_checkout_details() and a do_checkout() before showing him the Thank you page and this is 2 calls to a pretty slow payPal server.

My problem is, that when the user clicks on Pay Now! button, he is redirected back to my site but hangs at payPal for at least 5 seconds (while my server makes the 2 requests) before he can se anything. So the question is: Where should I make these two calls so the user doesnt have to wait so long before anything is shown to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using AJAX request is justwhat youwant. The idea is the following:

1. Output your page to client **not performing any paypal requests**
2. Create additional page/method that only performs paypal request and outputs data as `json`
3. On the outputted page place AJAX call to that new page
4. Process the response to know, if the request was successful.

For ajax calls youmight want to have a look at [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Most convenient way to output `json` data from PHP is using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) PHP function.

Comment: Thanks John! I thought of returning the user, and then making an AJAX call back to paypal, for the remaining 2 requests. But what if the person has no javascript? I am left with a customer willing to pay, but me not closing of payment with do_payment method.

Comment: In case of no javascript - leave a standard link to a page that will make the two calls and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable hooks and use the 'post_system' hook to make your two calls to the slow server. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html for more information.

However this will leave you with no easy way of showing any result of the two calls.